# pandas: finding and appending to first empty cell in specific columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following excel file.

```
1  |  A  |    B   |   C   |
---------------------------
2 | apple| banana | tomato|
---------------------------
3 |   3  |    4   |    4  |
---------------------------
4 |   9  |    7   |    3  |
---------------------------
5 |      |    2   |    1  |
---------------------------
6 |      |    8   |       |
---------------------------
7 |      |        |       |
---------------------------
```

I used **openpyxl** to read the excel file and convert to **pandas dataframe**.
The thing is, I have to loop through data and append to last row of specific column.

For example,

```
First data to append:   4 apple, 2 banana  
Second data to append:  3 apple
Third data to append:   3 apple, 2 banana, 5 tomato
```

After reading first data, the dataframe should look like:

```
1  |  A  |    B   |   C   |
---------------------------
2 | apple| banana | tomato|
---------------------------
3 |   3  |    4   |    4  |
---------------------------
4 |   9  |    7   |    3  |
---------------------------
5 |  *4  |    2   |    1  |
---------------------------
6 |      |    8   |       |
---------------------------
7 |      |   *2   |       |
---------------------------
```

After reading second data, the dataframe should look like:

```
1  |  A  |    B   |   C   |
---------------------------
2 | apple| banana | tomato|
---------------------------
3 |   3  |    4   |    4  |
---------------------------
4 |   9  |    7   |    3  |
---------------------------
5 |   4  |    2   |    1  |
---------------------------
6 |  *3  |    8   |       |
---------------------------
7 |      |    2   |       |
---------------------------
```

After reading third data, the dataframe should look like:

```
1  |  A  |    B   |   C   |
---------------------------
2 | apple| banana | tomato|
---------------------------
3 |   3  |    4   |    4  |
---------------------------
4 |   9  |    7   |    3  |
---------------------------
5 |   4  |    2   |    1  |
---------------------------
6 |   3  |    8   |   *5  |
---------------------------
7 |  *3  |    2   |       |
---------------------------
8 |      |   *2   |       |
---------------------------
```

Is there a way to append new data to first empty cell of a specific column? Thanks.

Comment: this is not very pandas trivial, I would append to list and then create a frame with it

Comment: @StevenG yeah look like this should be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I could do for you

```
d = defaultdict(list)

d['apple'] = [3, 9]
d['banana'] = [4, 7, 2, 8]
d['tomato'] = [4, 3, 1]

list_to_append = [
    dict(apple=4, banana=2),
    dict(apple=3),
    dict(apple=3, banana=2, tomato=5)
]

for a in list_to_append:
    for k, v in a.items():
        d[k].append(v)

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T

   apple  banana  tomato
0    3.0     4.0     4.0
1    9.0     7.0     3.0
2    4.0     2.0     1.0
3    3.0     8.0     5.0
4    3.0     2.0     NaN
5    NaN     2.0     NaN
```